# Modsecurity - Block request_uri but return code 200

Tags: security, nginx, endpoint, owasp, mod-security

I'm really new to modsecurity and I'm having some issues in understanding the rule editing.

I need to return 200 to the requests arriving form a specific endpoint that starts with `/myendpoint/` but I still want to deny the endpoint to do anything else.

I've checked on the web but I cannot find a solution that works fine for me.

```
# ModSec Rule Exclusion: 930100
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@beginsWith \/myendpoint\/" "phase:2,log,block,status:200,id:10000,ctl:ruleRemoveById=930100"
```

The rule above doesn't look like it's working at all and the requests are still blocked but the status 200 is not returned.

I need this because I have integrated the endpoint to a Telegram bot but if it receives a 403, the bot will keep sending the same message continuously for 24 hours.
I think that returning 200 but yet blocking the request to go further would solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very peculiar need. But anyways, Azurit has already pointed out the problem with the slashes. I think the other problem is the use of `block`. I'd do a `deny` combined with status. Much to my surprise, this works.

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@beginsWith /myendpoint/" "id:1000,phase:1,deny,status:200"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear: You want to block the request but still return HTTP code 200?

Btw, do NOT escape URI:
"@beginsWith /myendpoint/"

Comment: Yes that's what I want to achieve.
Why I shouldn't escape it in that way? I should escape the uri completely by providing the equal? If yes how would it be the correct solution?

Comment: This is correct syntax:
    SecRule REQUEST_URI "@beginsWith /myendpoint/" "phase:2,log,...

Comment: Ah escape the slashes :)
BTW that's correct, i want to simply return code 200 but still block the request.

It is not working with this `SecRule REQUEST_URI "@beginsWith /myendpoint/" "phase:2,log,block,status:200,id:10000,ctl:ruleRemoveById=930100"`

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Why you want to do this anyway? Are those requests really bad and needs to be blocked? Maybe just ignore them on application level?

Comment: In this case can I ignore the rule only for that specific endpoint so I can keep it turned on for other endpoints?

Comment: Yes, you can create an exclusion rule, something like:

`SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "@beginsWith /myendpoint/" "id:10000,phase:1,pass,t:none,nolog,ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=930110"`

You can set ID of the rule you want to 'ignore' at the end. Also, you can use multiple 'ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById'.

Comment: why is "REQUEST_FILENAME" instead of "REQUEST_URI"?
At the end of the story, what I want to intercept is the endpoint, not a specific file.
If I want to disable multiple rules, it's enough to add for instance 
`SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "@beginsWith /myendpoint/" "id:10000,phase:1,pass,t:none,nolog,ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=930110,ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=930100"` ?

Comment: REQUEST_URI contains also query string (?a=b), you don't need to check for that in this case (but both of them will work).

Yes, it looks ok.